# TypeError while using predict_proba on a previously built model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I trained and saved a model as below

```
filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
pickle.dump(rf, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

Now I am writing a webservice where I am getting a test dataset, so I load the model and predict probability

```
def getCuisine():
    content=jsonify(request.json)
    test = pd.io.json.json_normalize(request.json)
    tfidf_vect = pickle.load(open("vectorizer.pickle", "rb"))
    test['ingredients'] = [str(map(makeString, x)) for x in test['ingredients']]
    test_transform = tfidf_vect.transform(test['ingredients'].values)
    le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    X_test = test_transform
    y_test = le.fit_transform(test['cuisine'].values)

    # load the model
    filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
    #predict
    predicted_labels = loaded_model.predict_proba(X_test)
```

But I am getting error

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

in line `predicted_labels = loaded_model.predict_proba(X_test)`

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

Based on the comments, I tried below

```
content=request.json()
test = pd.io.json.json_normalize(content)
```

But then I get error `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` . See the sample input below.

Nonetheless don't think the issue is with reading the request. I tried panda's read with a local file as below but still getting the original error `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'`

```
test = pd.read_json('./test.json')
```

Sample input

```
[
  {
    "id": 25693,
    "cuisine": "southern_us",
    "ingredients": [
      "plain flour",
      "ground pepper",
      "salt",
      "tomatoes",
      "ground black pepper",
      "thyme",
      "eggs",
      "green tomatoes",
      "yellow corn meal",
      "milk",
      "vegetable oil"
    ]
  }
  ]
```

Comment: It should be `request.json()`

Comment: @coldspeed not sure what you meant?

Comment: Note the brackets in the comment, and then compare it with your code.

Comment: @VivekKumar see the edits